# Specific Event in Outlook 2007 - send email reminder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007, reminder

I have a specific event that recurs every so often on my Outlook Calendar...I would like Outlook (2007) to send a reminder every so often to a specific email address, reminding this person of this event.  How do I do this?

Comment: Is the recipient also using Outlook? If so, the best tool is a Task Request instead of an e-mail. You can make it recurring and also include it on your own task list. Of course, this won't work if the recipient doesn't use Outlook, declines to accept the task request or simply ignores task reminders.

Comment: @ Mike: no, the recipient does not use Outlook...just standard webmail...Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to go the macro route, I decided to use a webmail calendar and notification system, which supports email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a macro to trigger and email based on a task reminder, which you could use as a model http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&pub=6&lang=en&smp=10&cmd=showitem

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at http://www.tickletrain.com. I've had the same problem. But this works and there is a free plan.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.